# Cannot inject the depency at position #0 because TypeInfo not known

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsyringe

I'm having this trouble:

```
[ERROR] 14:07:18 Error: Cannot inject the dependency at position #0 of "ListInterviewPagesUseCase" constructor. Reason: TypeInfo not known for "InterviewPagesRepository"
```

**Container**

```
import { container } from "tsyringe";

import { InterviewPagesRepository } from "../../modules/interview/repositories/implementations/InterviewPagesRepository";

import "./providers";

container.registerSingleton(
  "InterviewPagesRepository",
  InterviewPagesRepository
);
```

**Controller**

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { container } from "tsyringe";

import { ListInterviewPagesUseCase } from "./ListInterviewPagesUseCase";

class ListInterviewPagesController {
  async handle(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const listInterviewPagesUseCase = container.resolve(
      ListInterviewPagesUseCase
    );

    const interviewPages = await listInterviewPagesUseCase.execute();

    return response.json(interviewPages);
  }
}

export { ListInterviewPagesController };
```

**UseCase**

```
import { inject, injectable } from "tsyringe";

import { InterviewPage } from "../../entities/InterviewPage";
import { IInterviewPagesRepository } from "../../repositories/IInterviewPagesRepository";

@injectable()
class ListInterviewPagesUseCase {
  constructor(
    @inject("InterviewPagesRepository")
    private interviewPagesRepository: IInterviewPagesRepository
  ) {}

  async execute(): Promise<InterviewPage[]> {
    const interviewPages = await this.interviewPagesRepository.all();

    return interviewPages;
  }
}

export { ListInterviewPagesUseCase };
```

It was working normally on windows, but now I've changed to mac and stopped working. I already put `delay` from `tsrynge` but still doesn`t work.

This happens when I call a route that use this repository, but seems to look ok, the database is created.

My imports in app file:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import "dotenv/config";
import "./database";
import "./shared/container";

import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";

import { router } from "./routes";
import swaggerFile from "./swagger.json";
```

Comment: Hi Leonard, Are InterviewPagesRepository implementing IInterviewPagesRepository interface?

Comment: Hi @LuisPauloPinto, yes, is implementing

Comment: Your code looks good... try to set singleton explicitly specifying the interface, like `container.registerSingleton<IInterviewPagesRepository>`

Comment: I did that too minutes ago, still doesn't work.

Comment: try to check out your container import inside app file. It must be one of the first imports.

Comment: I edited the post, this is how are my imports in app file

Comment: Hey, didn´t find any solution yet? This behaviour happens only to this repository? Also, maybe if you include your path strutcture and you repository and interface code would be good. I did a try with a code of mine with your usecase/container and works all good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider decorating `InterviewPagesRepository` with `@singleton`, instead of calling `container.registerSingleton` yourself:

```
import { singleton } from "tsyringe";

@singleton()
class InterviewPagesRepository {
```

The `@singleton` decorator [does invoke `registerSingleton()` inside](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/decorators/singleton.ts#L14), like you do, but it also stores it to be used in parameters of other constructors (see [1](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/decorators/singleton.ts#L13) → [2](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/decorators/injectable.ts#L13), and then [3](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/dependency-container.ts#L42) → [4](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/dependency-container.ts#L481) → [5](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/5363c9d6b54383626e7d57c1cbda2c406e836836/src/dependency-container.ts#L486)).